# He's dead, Jim! -- Phone is bricked, how screwed am I?

Tags: data-recovery, unbricking

This morning started with a catch-up, as always. I clicked a YouTube video, and the phone crashed. Just instantly crashed to the HTC logo screen, like it was rebooting.

It crashed again. And again. And again and again and again...

Eventually, it gave up.

It is so crashed, that plugging in the charger doesn't even light up the "charging" indicator light. Plugging it in to my PC causes it to identify as "Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM4)", which is about as far as "HTC 10" as you can get.

Considering I just last night achieved the highest level in a game I was playing, I'm somewhat more frustrated about this than normal.

What are my options, if any, for data recovery - bearing in mind it's encrypted (I enter my unlock pattern when I boot it normally)?

Comment: Just confirm the model of the phone, and if you rooted it.

Comment: Qualcomm 9008 mode is a mode for emergency recover. Unfortunately, the mode requires specially formatted images and tools for use with it, and HTC phones doesn't seem to get any...

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow It's an HTC 10, model number 2PS6200. Not rooted.

Comment: I contacted HTC Chat Support and they were able to help me go through some arcane menus and regain access. Honestly the phone probably just needed a thorough booting, but yeah. Access restored! Backing up NOW.

Comment: Proceed with caution... Going into Qloader mode means something serious is going on, not that it just needed a reboot. I would backup and perform a factory reset before using it again. I might even consider reflashing the factory image (RUU) of it's available for you're device variant

Comment: @acejavelin It happened again this morning but it came back. One thing I noticed is that the battery level was at 30% before, but only 1% after the crash. Do you think the battery could be shot?

Comment: Also, I have the backup option in Settings checked, and use cloud storage for Photos. Is that enough to cover my butt?